# Bash alias: fork a repo then cd and install

Tags: bash, git, macos, github

I'm trying to add an alias to my `.bash_profile` to automate cloning a GitHub repo. The cloning part is straightforward:

`alias createApp 'git clone https://github.com/user/repo.git'`

This allows me to execute:

```
createApp foo
createApp bar
```

How can I modify the cloning alias to `cd <destination_folder> && npm install` after cloning while keeping the current behavior of accepting a custom destination folder name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a shell function rather than an alias.

```
createApp() {
    git clone https://github.com/user/repo.git "$1" &&
    (cd "$1" && npm install)
}
```

Putting the `cd` in a subshell limits it to the `npm` command.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do this indirectly with the help of `.gitconfig`.

in `.gitconfig`:

```
[alias]
    createApp = "!f() { git clone https://github.com/user/repo.git \"$1\" && cd \"$1\" && npm install; }; f"
```

in `.bash_profile`:

```
alias createApp='git createApp'
```

I will keep this question open to answer whether there is a direct (or better) way to do it.